# Why does the call of python's fcntl.ioctl gives a Invalid argument error

Tags: python, python-2.7, fcntl

I am trying to utilize the command `fcntl.ioctl` from python's [fcntl package](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html) in the following manner

```
buf = array.array('h', [0])
fcntl.ioctl(file_handler, 21780)
fcntl.ioctl(file_handler, 21780, buf)
fcntl.ioctl(file_handler, 21780, buf, 1)
```

i.e. all three versions of it, with `file_handler` a file handler created with `open`. Each gives me the same error:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Simple question: How do I properly make a call to `fcntl.ioctl`? Or to use `fcntl.fcntl` instead?

Comment: What's the magic constant supposed to do, and why don't you use the symbolic ones in `fcntl` or `termios`?

Comment: First, `file_handler` is a usb device (e.g. `/dev/ttyACM0`), the number should hard-reset the device (see http://www.roman10.net/how-to-reset-usb-device-in-linux/), and for that I could not found the corresponding variable name in `fcntl` or `termios`. If you know them, that would be doubtless much more convenient. In summary, I want to hard-reset a device connected to the given port as described in the links, only under python.

Comment: I guess those are not exported by the Python standard library. If the first `ioctl` fails, then apparently 21780 is not a valid operation. You might be missing a driver.

Comment: @larsmans: The corresponding C code seem to work, at last no error message, the magic number is 21780, and in most(?) cases the reset with the operation 21780 seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using the wrong file. Your example C code references `/dev/bus/usb/<bus_id>/<device_id>`, not `/dev/ttyACM0`.